# Get current namepace on Snippet

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, namespaces, code-snippets

I want to inject the current namepace on my snippet.
Does anyone have an idea to help me ?

**ClassName** function returns the name of the class that contains the inserted snippet. There is something for namespace ?

Thanks,
Fabien

Snippet sample:

```
    <Declarations>
        <Literal default="true" Editable="false">
            <ID>classname</ID> 
            <ToolTip>Class name</ToolTip> 
            <Function>ClassName()</Function> 
            <Default>ClassNamePlaceholder</Default> 
        </Literal>
        <Literal Editable="false">
            <ID>namespace</ID> 
            < ??? />
        </Literal>
    </Declarations>
    <Code Language="CSharp">
        <![CDATA[ 
            $namespace$ $classname$ 
        ]]>
    </Code>
```

expected result :  "TheCurrentNamepace.OfMyClass" "MyClassName"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I choose to use Macros to call my snippet and inject the namespace on it.

Call snippet:

```
Sub InsertMySnippet()
    DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text = "mySnippetShortcut"
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.InsertTab")

    Dim selection As TextSelection = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection
    selection.Insert(GetNamespace())

    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.InsertTab")
End Sub
```

Getting namespace:

```
Private Function GetNamespace() As String
    Dim classInfo As CodeClass2 = GetClassElement()
    Return classInfo.FullName
End Function

Private Function GetClassElement() As CodeClass2
    Try
        Dim selection As TextSelection = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection
        Dim fileCodeModel As FileCodeModel2 = DTE.ActiveDocument.ProjectItem.FileCodeModel
        Dim element As CodeElement2 = fileCodeModel.CodeElementFromPoint(selection.TopPoint, vsCMElement.vsCMElementClass)
        Return element
    Catch
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```